# What would cause click events to stop working in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm sorry for the vague question, but I'm dealing with a very vague bug.

Sometimes, in IE 11, my app just "dies." The pointer changes when you hover over a clickable element, but left-clicking does nothing, nor does right-clicking. Hover also stops working... if you hover over an element that has :hover CSS, the :hover CSS doesn't work. This only happens on specific pages, but not all the time... sometimes you load the page and clicking works, sometimes you load the page and clicking doesn't work.

If I hit refresh, clicking starts to work again.

If I use the keyboard to tab to an element and press "enter," I am able to follow a link I wasn't able to click on.

No errors in the console window.

IE version is RTM 11.0.9600.16428, running on Windows Server 2008 R2. I think it has also happened on Windows 7 and 7 Pro machines. I can't reproduce it on my Windows 8.1 machine with IE 11.0.9600.17728--clicking works consistently there.

Is it possible that, somehow, all the click handlers are getting taken off of everything? Even the window itself? That would explain why right-click stops working as well as left... I can't even get a context menu to use "View Source" or "Inspect Element." Nothing!

Comment: Could you provide some code, preferably in a fiddle?

Comment: Not really. There's a lot of code and most of it is proprietary to my employer. It's an MVVM with KnockoutJS and SammyJS. I think I have provided enough information for someone to think through the problem.

Comment: I have experienced this bug on Win Server 2008 R2 using MVC, jQuery ajax and SVG. Just spend a day trying to fix. TQ

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this: The problem turned out to be a bug specific to IE 11 for Win 7/Server 2008 R2. It doesn't happen in IE 11 for Win8.1+ or for any other browser.

Here's more info on the bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/205775/

I "fixed" it with one line of CSS:

```
use {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I ran into this exact same issue today and had tried various approaches to solving it. I wasn't able to to find any solution until I came across this post. What a bizarre bug!

Comment: Best answer ever. The last 5 hours debugging this absolutely bizarre scenario haven't been in vain!

Comment: I took a day to investigate this issue. I thought it was a javascript bug. Thank you so much!
Btw, the link https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796745/mouse-events-are-not-delivered-at-all-anymore-when-inside-an-svg-a-use-is-removed-from-the-dom doesn't work anymore, if you have something else please provide us. Thanks.

Comment: @nguyen-tran I've updated the link to the bug report.

Comment: Same thing happened today for me as well. We have an react-app that all the sudden stopped working in IE11 for Windows 7 computers. Kinda odd, as it had been working for "ages" until today, and then a simple "click"-event triggered this in IE11. And, its not that it was the first "click"-even either. Quite odd and confusing. Long live IE11 :-) bizarre..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

The text was entered into the input, after pressing Enter, an event `onKeyDown` was called, and the data was reloaded with recreating input element as well.
After that, the interface elements did not respond to mouse clicks. But as soon as you click on the different elements - it started working again.

My solution: before reloading the data, I had to trigger `blur` for the input.